# Evaluation of $ \int^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}_0 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}_0 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}}dx$

What I try : Put $x=\sin\theta$ and $dx=\cos\theta d\theta$ and changing limits, we get

$\displaystyle I =\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta(1+\cos\theta)}}\cos\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle I =\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_0\frac{\sin^2\theta\cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-2\sin^2\theta\cos\frac{\theta}{2}}}d\theta$

Now I did not understand what substitution used here to  solve further.

Please have a look on that problem, Thanks

Comment: $1+\cos\theta\neq 2\cos\frac\theta2.$ There should be a square in the right hand side. Not that I think the approach will be successful

Comment: With $t=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $x=\sqrt{1-t^2}$, $dx/dt= -t/\sqrt{1-t^2}$,
$$
I= -\int_1^{1/\surd 2} \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2(1+t)}} \frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
$$
$$
= \int_1^{1/\surd 2} \frac{t^2-1}{\sqrt{1-(1-t^2)(1+t)}} \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1-(1-t^2)(1+t)}} tdt
$$
$$
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^3+t^2-t}} tdt
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2+t-1}} \sqrt{ t}dt
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{(1-t)(1+t)}}{\sqrt{(t+\varphi)(t-\varphi+1)}} \sqrt{ t}dt
$$
with $\varphi=(\surd 5+1)/2$ the golden ratio.

Comment: My guess is this is a hypergeometric result

Comment: Which is the source of the problem?!

Answer (score 3):

$$
I =\int_0^{1/\surd 2} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}}dx
=\sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{i} \int_0^{1/\surd 2} x^2(-x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}))^i dx
$$
$$
=\sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{i} (-)^i\int_0^{1/\surd 2} x^{2+2i}(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})^i dx
=\sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{i} (-)^i \sum_{k=0}^i \binom{i}{k} \int_0^{1/\surd 2} x^{2+2i}\sqrt{1-x^2}^k dx
$$
$$
=\sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{i} (-)^i \sum_{k=0}^i \binom{i}{k} \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin^{2+2i}\theta \sqrt{\cos^2\theta }^k \cos\theta d\theta
$$
$$
=\sum_{i\ge 0} \binom{-1/2}{i} (-)^i \sum_{k=0}^i \binom{i}{k} \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin^{2+2i}\theta \cos^{k+1}\theta  d\theta
$$
where a table of $\sum_{k=0}^i \binom{i}{k} \int_0^{\pi/4} \sin^{2+2i}\theta \cos^{k+1}\theta  d\theta$
starts as:

$$
i=0: \sqrt{2}/12 \approx 0.117851130
$$

$$
i=1: \sqrt{2}/40-1/48+\pi/64 \approx 0.06360939094
$$

$$
i=2: 29\sqrt{2}/2016-1/24+5\pi/256 \approx 0.04003591469
$$

$$
i=3: 61\sqrt{2}/6336-9/160+91\pi/4096 \approx 0.02716150265
$$

$$
i=4: 3734\sqrt{2}/549120-461/6720+51\pi/2048 \approx 0.01927161949
$$
so that converges.
Summing the first $i$ terms gives the partial sums:
$$
i=2: I\approx 0.164669293681046
$$
$$
i=12: I\approx 0.189560752031611287833
$$
$$
i=22: I\approx 0.1907652403957029
$$
$$
i=32: I\approx 0.19088880295040084979
$$
$$
i=42: I\approx 0.1909046824569803959927
$$
$$
i=52: I\approx  0.1909069677820408385038590
$$
$$
i=62: I\approx  0.1909073200612563243164
$$
$$
i=72: I\approx  0.1909073769353998240203
$$
Alternatively
With $t=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, $x=\sqrt{1-t^2}$, $dx/dt= -t/\sqrt{1-t^2}$,
$$
I= -\int_1^{1/\surd 2} \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2(1+t)}} \frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
= -\int_1^{1/\surd 2} \frac{1-x^2-1}{\sqrt{1-(1-t^2)(1+t)}} \frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
$$
$$
= \int_1^{1/\surd 2} \frac{t^2-1}{\sqrt{1-(1-t^2)(1+t)}} \frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{1-(1-t^2)(1+t)}} tdt
$$
$$
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^3+t^2-t}} tdt
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{\sqrt{t^2+t-1}} \sqrt{ t}dt
= \int_{1/\surd 2}^1 \frac{\sqrt{(1-t)(1+t)}}{\sqrt{(t+\varphi)(t-\varphi+1)}} \sqrt{ t}dt
$$
where $\varphi=(\surd 5+1)/2\approx 1.61803$ is the golden ratio.
Since there are products of 5 roots of linear polynomials with distinct roots at $-\varphi, -1, 0, \varphi-1, 1$ in the integrand, one may expand one of the 5 in a series around any of the other to reduce the complexity to 4 roots, i.e., Elliptic Integrals. The natural choice is to take the root which coincides with one of the integral limits.
One may expand $\surd t$ as a power series at $t=1$,
$$
\surd t = \sum_{l\ge 0}(-)^l\binom{1/2}{l} (1-t)^l
$$
$$
I = \sum_{l\ge 0} (-1)^l\binom{1/2}{l} \int_{1/\surd 2}^1
\frac{(1-t)^{l+1/2}(1+t)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(t+\varphi)(t-\varphi+1)}} dt
$$
$$
= \sum_{l\ge 0} (-1)^{l+1}\binom{1/2}{l} \int_{1-1/\surd 2}^0
\frac{v^{l+1/2}(2-v)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(1+\varphi-v)(2-v-\varphi)}} dv
$$
$$
= \sum_{l\ge 0} (-1)^l\binom{1/2}{l} \int_0^{1-1/\surd 2}
\frac{v^{l+1/2}(2-v)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(1+\varphi-v)(2-\varphi-v)}} dv
$$
$$
= \sum_{l\ge 0} (-1)^l\binom{1/2}{l} \int_0^{1-1/\surd 2}
\frac{(v-d)^{l+1/2}(b-v)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(a-v)(c-v)}} dv
$$
where $a\equiv 1+\varphi$, $b=2$, $c=2-\varphi$, $d=0$ and $a>b>c>d$.
This is a series over elliptic integrals.
The Byrd-Friedman table of integrals provides [252.21] for $l=0$:
$$
\int_0^{1-1/\surd 2}
\frac{(v-d)^{1/2}(b-v)^{1/2}}{\sqrt{(a-v)(c-v)}} dv
=
(a-d)(b-d)\alpha^2 g\int_0^{u_2}\frac{ sn^2 u dn^2 u}{(1-\alpha^2 sn^2 u)^2}du
$$
and the terms for $l>0$ can be reduced with the aid of [252.11].

Comment: Nice to see you here R.J. Mathar !
I heard about you :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly,
$$I=\int\limits^{\large\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}_0 \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2(1+\sqrt{1-x^2})}}\,\text dx
=\int\limits^{\large\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}_0 {\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}}}}\,\text dx$$
$$=\int\limits^{\large\frac{1}{\sqrt2}}_0 \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\dbinom{-\frac12}{n-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^n\,\text dx
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\dbinom{-\frac12}{n-1}\operatorname I_n,$$
where
$$I_n=\int\limits_0^{\large\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\,\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)^n\,\text dx
=\dfrac12\,\int\limits_0^{\large\frac{1}{2}}\,y^{n-\large\frac12}(1-y)^{\large -\frac n2}\,\text dy =\dfrac12\operatorname{B}_{\large\frac12}\left(n+\frac12,1-\frac n2\right),$$
and $\;\text B\;$ is [Incomplete Beta-Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html).

Therefore,
$$I=\dfrac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\dbinom{-\frac12}{n-1}
\operatorname{B}_{\large\frac12}\left(n+\frac12,1-\frac n2\right).\,$$
My attempts to get a closed form were insuccessive.

The partial sums are:
$$I(52)\approx 0.19090738838 \dots$$
$$I(99)\approx 0.1909073883986198163 \dots$$
$$I(199)\approx 0.1909073883986198167553151494826012\dots$$
$$I(399)\approx 0.19090738839861981675531514948260139556077387013863391343248542881\dots$$
Numerical calculations of the integral give:
$$I≈0.190907388398619816755315149482601395560773870138633913432485428851994\dots$$